Az Powershell - not able to read CSV file contents
I am trying to get contents of a backedup CSV users file and compare it with current settings and want to assign (unassigned users). I am accessing this CSV file from file storage - though the file is listed, not able to read the contents using the Import-Csv. See code below and do help. Been struggling with this from yesterday!
 # Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity (automation account)
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

# Set the subscription
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Define the session host details
$storageaccountname = "xxxxxxxx"
$StorageAccountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$filesharename = "userassignment"
$resourceGroupName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$FileName = storageaccountname/csvfilename

# Set the context of the Storage Account
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageaccountname -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

#Get the file from the File Share
    Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $filesharename -Path $FileName -Context $ctx -Destination "C:\app"
    # Get the contents of backed up users CSV
    #$csvPath = "C:\app\w20240501.csv"
    $csvfile = Import-Csv -Path "C:\app\w20240501.csv"
    Write-Output "csvfile: $csvfile"
No errors showing but csvfile variable is empty- its not getting imported 


Any error messages?

PowerShell/.Net has very clear error messages by itself which you are in fact destroying with a worthless "Failed to retrieve CSV content $_" message. In other words: remove the Try/Catch and focus on the actual error message. If you still can't figure out the cause of the issue, please, edit your question and add the original error message.

@iRon Will definitely catch the real error msg and edit.

@iRon Have added the error msg and the updated code too.

@RuiJarimba - Have added the error msg and the updated code too.

That is a weird error as it includes the literal variable name. Please paste the exact and complete (including the position) in the question.

Can you confirm the exact code in your post actually reproduces the error? For example your call to Get-AzStorageFileContent is currently commented out and you're referencing a variable $backupFilename in $backupFilePath = $subdirectorypath + "/" + $backupFilename that isn't defined. If you can't reproduce the error by cutting and pasting the code from your post then it's going to be hard for other people to debug it as well, as we're having to guess what your code really looks like :-). Please also post the full error message, and any other output from the script...

@mclayton I have added the exact code and also given the full error msg.

Thanks. In your latest edit you’re not actually calling Get-AzStorageFileContent, just Get-AzStorageFile which, “Lists directories and files for a path.” according to the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefile?view=azps-11.6.0 which would explain why the file hasn’t been downloaded. Also, your code still doesn’t match the error message - the file names are different. Are there any other discrepancies between the code you’ve posted and the code you’re running locally?

@mclayton I'm first listing the file in the fileshare storage account amd then using Import-csv to download the file content. Should I also use Get-AzStorageFileContent to list the contents of the csv file?

You define $filesharename as "userassignment", so where does the $csvpath variable get the C:\app from? Are you sure $csvpath =  $filesharename + "/" + $subdirectorypath + "/" + $csvFileName results in a valid path where the file is?

@Theo I first tried the Get-AzStorageFileContent and as it didnt work, tried the import-CSV - I have tried giving the full path as I hve a File share, directory and the file name itself as path. Still it does not work. In Get-AzStorageFileContent I have passed parameters of Sharename, Path (as above) and Context too. Am I missing something else here?

No, i meant you never combine the path with a root (C:\app), so what do you see for $csvpath ?

@Theo for $csvpath it shows below output - csvpath: userassignment/wp_20240501/wp_20240501.csv. and the error msg shows - Import-Csv : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\app\userassignment\wvdpool-nonprod-pp-p_20240501\wvdpool-nonprod-pp-p_20240501.csv'. At line:32 char:12 + $csvdata = Import-Csv -Path $csvpath -Delimiter "," + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], DirectoryNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand - Pretty sure that the source path is not correct, but cannot figure this out. Need help.

You need to prepend the ROOT for the filename to make it fully qualified. Since you do not, PowerShell resolves your path by combining the current path with the relative path you give it in $csvpath. You say you have a share where the file should be, so combine the rootpath for that share with the rest of your path. For instance, if your share is at \\AzServer\SomeFolder, you can join the elements like $csvpath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine('\\AzServer\SomeFolder',$filesharename, $subdirectorypath, $csvFileName) to get a FullName for the file.


I'm first listing the files in the fileshare storage account and then using Import-csv to download the file content.

I agree with mclayton's comment, Get-AzstorageFile is used to "list directories and files for a path"; you need to use Get-AzStorageFileContent. This command will download the file to local and read your CSV file.
You can use the script below to list the files from a particular directory and also read the CSV file.
Script:
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

# Set the subscription
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# Define the session host details
$storageaccountname = "venkat123"
$StorageAccountKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$filesharename = "share1"
$resourceGroupName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageaccountname -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
Write-Output "ctx: $ctx"

$subdirectoryname = "wp_20240501"  
$subdirectorypath = $subdirectoryname
$csvFileName = "titanic.csv"

# List files within the directory of the Azure File Share
$files = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $filesharename -Context $ctx -Path $subdirectorypath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-AzStorageFile

# Output the list of files
if ($files) {
    Write-Output "List of files in '$subdirectorypath':"
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Write-Output $file.Name
    }

    # Check if the CSV file exists
    $csvFile = $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $csvFileName }

    if ($csvFile) {
        # Define the local directory where the CSV file will be downloaded
        $localDestination = "<You destination path>" #c:\users\app\

        # Download the CSV file to the local destination
        $csvFilePath = Join-Path -Path $localDestination -ChildPath $csvFileName
        Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $filesharename -Context $ctx -Path "$subdirectorypath/$csvFileName" -Destination $csvFilePath -Force

        # Check if the file was downloaded successfully
        if (Test-Path $csvFilePath -PathType Leaf) {
            # Read the content of the downloaded CSV file using Import-Csv
            $csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

            # Output the CSV data
            Write-Output $csvData
        } else {
            Write-Output "Failed to download the CSV file to the local destination."
        }
    } else {
        Write-Output "CSV file '$csvFileName' not found in the specified directory."
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "No files found in the specified directory."
}

Output:
ctx: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext
List of files in 'wp_20240501':
03-04-2024 (1).html
04-04-2024.html
April-04-2024 (1).html
response_1712214210668.html
titanic.csv


PassengerId : 1
Survived    : 0
Pclass      : 3
Name        : Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
Sex         : male
Age         : 22
SibSp       : 1
Parch       : 0
Ticket      : A/5 21171
Fare        : 7.25
Cabin       : 
Embarked    : S


Reference:
Get-AzureStorageFileContent (Azure.Storage) | Microsoft Learn
Update:
You can use the below code in azure runbook to read the csv file.
Script:
$subdirectoryname = "wp_20240501"  
$subdirectorypath = $subdirectoryname
$csvFileName = "titanic.csv"

# List files within the directory of the Azure File Share
$files = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $filesharename -Context $ctx -Path $subdirectorypath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Get-AzStorageFile

# Output the list of files
if ($files) {
    Write-Output "List of files in '$subdirectorypath':"
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        Write-Output $file.Name
    }

    # Check if the CSV file exists
    $csvFile = $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $csvFileName }

    if ($csvFile) {
        # Download the CSV file to a temporary location
        $tempFilePath = Join-Path $env:TEMP -ChildPath $csvFileName
        Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $filesharename -Context $ctx -Path "$subdirectoryname/$csvFileName" -Destination $tempFilePath -Force

        # Read the content of the downloaded CSV file using Import-Csv
        $csvData = Import-Csv -Path $tempFilePath

        # Output the CSV data
        Write-Output $csvData

        # Clean up the temporary file
        #Remove-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Force
    } else {
        Write-Output "CSV file '$csvFileName' not found in the specified directory."
    }
} else {
    Write-Output "No files found in the specified directory."
}

The above code will temporary path in azure automation and read your csv file.
Output:


I will try this and let you know.

Sure,let know once you checked.

I am running this script directly from azure portal in the runbook- so In the import-csv command I'm getting the same path not found error so its unable to access the csv file from the portal, no matter what path I give. But when i run the same in Windows powershell ISE while connecting to thr automation account with azureautomationtoolkit addon - It's working perfectly and I can see the result in the azure portal. Why is it not wiorking in the portal for the path? what path should i give to access contents of the csv file in the azure fileshare storage?

@NaliniB Check the updated answer it will read csv file from azure runbook.

The path in which the file should get imported is c:\app which is the cloud shell path
In get-az file content in destination I give this path  and import the CSV file to this destination but it's not getting imported - CODE : #Get the file from the File Share
Get-AzStorageFileContent -ShareName $filesharename -Path $FileName -Context $ctx -Destination "C:\app"
# Get the contents of backed up users CSV
#$csvPath = "C:\app\w_20240501.csv"
$csvfile = Import-Csv -Path "C:\app\p_20240501.csv"
Write-Output "csvfile: $csvfile"

You can create temporary path and able to read the csv file why you need particularly from "C:\app"?

I am givng c:\app becasue I want this script to be run from Azure runbook itself so want this file to be downloaded in file storage location itself

If i give with C:\app" it worked perfectly in automation account check here https://i.imgur.com/r9xLhkM.png

Hope this address your issue.

Csn you tell me what configuration i need ? I have contributor access- is there anything else i need?

Can you share the erro screenshot and script which could be useful to me?

I have edited the script in the first message

Try to execute my exact code which I given with proper file name.

In my first script just change the $localDestination = "C:\app" and try wait for few minutes to execute.
